# How to delete a text file in google colab standard path?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using google colab and have saved some png's and now i want to delete them is there any way to do it, my current path is \content.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `%cd` magic to switch to whatever directory holds the files and then use shell commands to remove them.

For example, if you have a file in `/content/directory/a.png`, run:

```
%cd /content/directory
!rm a.png
```

If you want to remove all `.png` files, adjust your `rm` command like so: `!rm *.png`.